# XNA: How to change texture reference midgame?

Tags: c#, xna

I'm currently making a game in XNA. I have been going well so far but I don't know how to change the texture of a sprite whilst running the game. An example of this would be. When the character is still that's one image, then when he walks that's a different image. How would I make this happen?

Answer (score 0):

Run checks and just set the instance's `Texture2D texture` to some other texture from your preloaded library.

I usually load all the textures in my content folder into a dictionary and use like so:

```
var StringTextureDic = new Dictionary<string, Texture2D>();

// code that loads all textures into the dictionary, file names being keys

// whenever I need to assign some texture, I do this:
if (!playerIsMoving)
    Player.texture = StringTextureDic["player standing"];

if (playerIsMoving)
    Player.texture = StringTextureDic["player moving"];
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but whenever I use this dictionary method of yours the game crashes and says "The given key was not present in the dictionary."

Answer (score 0):

Well, actually, change the player texture midgame is a bad idea. In such cases, i prefer to use a texture sheet.

```
Rectangle frame;
int curFrame;
int frameWidth;  
int frameHeight;
int runAnimationLength;

Update()
{
//Handle your "animation code"
if(playerIsMoving)
     curFrame++; //Running
     if(curFrame == runAnimationLength)
          curFrame =0;
else 
curFrame = 0; //Standing still
}
Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
{
frame = new Rectangle(curFrame*frameWidth,curFrame*frameHeight,frameWidth,frameHeight);
spriteBatch.Draw(
texture,
position,
**frame**, 
color, 
rotation, 
origin, 
SpriteEffects.None,
1);
}
```

Comment: Why is changing player texture midgame a bad idea?

Comment: Well, it's uses much more resources and less flexible.
Case with multiple files:
1. Assign texture to your variable
2. Draw this texture
3. Unload old texture
4. Load new texture
5. Assign new texture
6. Draw new texture

Case with texture sheet:
1. Assign texture to your variable
2. Draw(Drawing and cycling though frames at the same time)

Comment: You assume that there is texture unloading somewhere, but there isn't, same as with using a sprite strip — you never unload the frames that are rarely used. There might be performance increase when using a sprite strip rather than single textures, but it's out of the scope of this question.